# Is it possible to add a custom header for a StackLayoutPanel using UiBinder?

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

Using GWT 2.3 I want to be able to specify a custom header for my StackLayoutPanel.

I can do this programmatically by calling StackLayoutPanels

```
public void add(final Widget widget, Widget header, double headerSize);
```

method, but when I try and do it from UiBinder using the following code

```
<g:FlowPanel addStyleNames="{style.widget}">
    <g:StackLayoutPanel unit='EM' addStyleNames="{style.inner}">
        <g:stack>
            <g:header size='3'>
                <c:NavigatorHeader title="People"/>
            </g:header>
            <g:VerticalPanel>
                <g:Label>tom</g:Label>
                <g:Label>dick</g:Label>
                <g:Label>harry</g:Label>
            </g:VerticalPanel>
        </g:stack>
        <g:stack>
            <g:header size='3'>
                <c:NavigatorHeader title="Cars"/>
            </g:header>
            <g:VerticalPanel>
                <g:Label>estate</g:Label>
                <g:Label>saloon</g:Label>
                <g:Label>hatchback</g:Label>
            </g:VerticalPanel>
        </g:stack>
    </g:StackLayoutPanel>
</g:FlowPanel>
```

I get a

```
Found widget in an HTML context Element <c:NavigatorHeader title='People'>
```

exception.

How do I do this or is this not supported from UiBinder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doh - found it.

Looking in the [StackLayoutPanel UiBinder documentation](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/tags/2.3.0/user/src/com/google/gwt/uibinder/elementparsers/StackLayoutPanelParser.java) found I just need to use the element g:customHeader in place of g:header.